# Facebook UI Grab Locale (location)

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, fb.ui

How would I do this but using Graph API to grab locale and display content based on country?.

```
FB.login(function(response) {
             if data.get('user').get('locale') = "en_GB" {
                $("#footer a").text("URL HERE");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the facebook javascript sdk for authenticating the user, then you get a signed request for the user, as it states in the [signed request guide](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/):

> When using the JS SDK for authentication, the authResponse object
>   contains a signed_request property which is used to transfer
>   information about the authenticated user.

The signed request has the user field which is:

> A JSON object containing the locale string, country string and the age
>   object (containing the min and max number range of the age) for the
>   current user

You should get the locale value even if the user hasn't authenticated your app so that you could show content that matches it.

---

## Edit

You have a few ways to get the *authResponse*, the most basic of which is to use [FB.login](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/), like so:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        console.log(response.authResponse);
    }
    else {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: Would you happen to have an example based on the JS above please?.

Comment: Then I need to use FB.api to grab locale? e.g

FB.api('/me', function(response) {
  alert('Your name is ' + response.name);
});

Comment: No, you don't need to use *FB.api*, it's enough to just get the authResponse using *FB.login*, *FB.getLoginStatus* or *FB.getAuthResponse*.

Comment: Oh so, authresponse then use jquery to run functions based on locale location?

Comment: I just answered on how to find the locale using facebook, from there on it's you call what to do.

Comment: Update. How's that above?. Thanks.

Comment: Looks pretty much ok, except that it should be *response.authResponse.get('user').get('locale')*. Just try it a few times and you'll figure it out.